# SqLite query with multiple aggregation functions are slow - need help to optimize the query

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, subquery, max

I need help optimizing this query for sqlite (query run from php):

```
select max(aid) as aid, max(mid) as mid ,max(tid) as tid,
       max(m.id) as m_mid, max(t.id) as m_tid, max(a.id) as m_aid
from   dview, T_DATA t, M_DATA m, A_DATA a
```

Field not accessed by table name prefix (ex `a.id`) are from dview, other are from tables specified.

Running it in sqlite with few hundreds of records in each table takes over a minute.

I know that indexes won't fix because sqlite takes care of them only if a single aggregation is performed. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FROM` clause:

```
from dview, T_DATA t, M_DATA m, A_DATA a
```

creates a cartesian product of all the combinations of rows of the 4 datasets and it produces huge dataset on which the aggregation is finally done.

As it is, your code is equivalent to:

```
SELECT MAX(aid) AS aid, MAX(mid) AS mid, MAX(tid) AS tid,
       (SELECT MAX(id) FROM M_DATA) AS m_mid, 
       (SELECT MAX(id) FROM T_DATA) AS m_tid, 
       (SELECT MAX(id) FROM A_DATA) AS m_aid
FROM dview;
```

which should perform significantly better.

Comment: Thank you, it's way faster. In the original form it took 60 secons in this form it takes 5ms!